# DDD Reporting Scenarios

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to create a reporting/analysis web app that will use MVC3, EF and DDD approach. I'm havign a hard time to come up with entities or object classes for aggregated tables on existing database. For example, I have Orders and OrderLine as an aggregate and Customers as Entity. This three objects can be modeled using DDD approach but what if I want to have an OrdersAggregate Table which will contatins all the details like customer name, payment type, etc.

Should I create an object class here which contain the properties of customername, payment type, etc. or let EF create his sql query and join related tables? I'm worrying about performance here and this will be deploed on a cloud and a huge volume of transactions awaits.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize [CQRS](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/) and [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) in some aspects to take the benefit of separating read model from write.

Dont have to implement the entire architecture, just separate the read from write model and services, this make the read model send customized DTOs flat for rading and analysis purposes, and a strong domain model on the other hand in the write model for business logic handling.

check [this](http://moh-abed.com/2011/09/13/pure-old-ddd-with-a-twist-from-cqrs/) and [this](http://sellandbuy.codeplex.com/) example

Comment: But this will still do Joins right? or your DTO's are caching the data that was fetched earlier?

Comment: You have two approaches, either fetch and join on request, or better construct a cache, the best but more complicated is to create another database with customized tables (flat) for queries, and whenever the domain layer change state publish an event and make a handler to flatten the data from the state change and put it in the query database

Comment: So OrderAggregate table will be in my Model Class am I right? or this will be act as my DTO?

Comment: you will have 2 models, one project is domain model will have Order Aggregate designed in an object oriented way, another project will be called Read Model, with DTOs customized for reading like an Order DTO with required data for reading only.

you can at the end either have one database with two different mapping layers (one to map domain entities into  tables, and the other to map DTOs into tables) check the sample for more details of this approach

another approach is to have 2 databases one for read and one for write, the read tables will be flat and cusomized for reading and analysis

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that DDD is not suitable for doing reporting, statistics etc.
Some experts in like Jimmy Nilsson tells you to bypass your domain with regular dataacces.
If you just think about it, there is not much domain logic in presenting the data. It just seems like an overhead in doing layers and DDD style with ORM, repositories, aggregateroots etc just for view data.

Just a personal opinion.
/Good Luck and best regards Magnus

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a DTO class for this purpose, and fill using a dataset returned from a SQL command (hand-made) with your joins and relationships.

Is only a suggestion, because I used this approach to a similar problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking this also as well but I want to utilize EF throughout the project